# Unable to resolve superclass of LoginActivity extends FacebookActivity

Tags: android, android-manifest, runtime-error, oncreate, main-activity

```
11-29 11:23:06.101: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at 
com.mypackage.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
```

I usually don't see this unless it's a problem with the Manifest or the activity wasn't correctly initialized. Only problem is, it is both initialized and correctly, spelled, typed, etc, in the Manifest. Anyone have any other ideas what this could possibly be.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    public static Intent loginActivityIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle MainActivityState)
    {
        super.onCreate(MainActivityState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Line41->loginActivityIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
LoginActivity
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </activity>
```

At the top of this logcat it states "unable to resolve superclass of loginactivity. The LoginActivity is from Facebook SDK, the super class is FacebookActivity, and it's not throwing me an error during editing.

```
11-29 11:38:41.642: W/dalvikvm(330): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/limbones/profilelife/LoginActivity; (462)
11-29 11:38:41.683: W/dalvikvm(330): Link of class 'Lcom/limbones/profilelife/LoginActivity;' failed
11-29 11:38:41.683: W/dalvikvm(330): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/limbones/profilelife/PLLoginActivity; (471)
11-29 11:38:41.683: W/dalvikvm(330): Link of class 'Lcom/limbones/profilelife/PLLoginActivity;' failed
11-29 11:38:41.692: E/dalvikvm(330): Could not find class 'com.limbones.profilelife.PLLoginActivity', referenced from method com.limbones.profilelife.PLMainActivity.onCreate
11-29 11:38:41.692: W/dalvikvm(330): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 475 (Lcom/limbones/profilelife/PLLoginActivity;) in Lcom/limbones/profilelife/PLMainActivity;
11-29 11:38:41.692: D/dalvikvm(330): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000a
11-29 11:38:41.702: D/dalvikvm(330): VFY: dead code 0x000c-002b in Lcom/limbones/profilelife/PLMainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
11-29 11:38:41.942: D/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
11-29 11:38:41.942: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.limbones.profilelife.PLLoginActivity
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.limbones.profilelife.PLMainActivity.onCreate(PLMainActivity.java:43)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-29 11:38:42.072: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 11:38:44.592: I/Process(330): Sending signal. PID: 330 SIG: 9
```

UPDATE:

This is the only thing that is different in my Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGINACTIVITY"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </activity>
```

The activity it links to is just called LoginActivity, should I have included the prefixes as well?

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.limbones.profilelife;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.FacebookActivity;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class LoginActivity extends FacebookActivity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle LoginActivity)
    {
        super.onCreate(LoginActivity);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_login_activity);
        this.openSession();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        if (state.isOpened())
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(
            this.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                {
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.facebookWelcome);
                        welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

PLLoginActivity.Java

```
package com.limbones.profilelife;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class PLLoginActivity extends LoginActivity
{
    public Intent registerActivityIntent;
    public Intent notImplementedIntent;
    public Intent facebookLoginIntent;

    public void onCreate(Bundle LoginPage)
    {
        super.onCreate(LoginPage);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_page);
        registerActivityIntent = new Intent(this, PLRegisterActivity.class);
        notImplementedIntent = new Intent(this, PLNotImplemented.class);
        facebookLoginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    }

    public void backButton(View v)
    {
        finish();
    }

    public void registerButton(View v)
    {
        this.startActivity(registerActivityIntent);
    }

    public void loginButton(View v)
    {
        this.startActivity(notImplementedIntent);
    }

    public void fbLogin(View v)
    {
        this.startActivity(facebookLoginIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your complete `logcat`

Comment: Check all the pacakage and activity names again in manifest

Comment: Full LogCat posted. Thank you for your help. I don't see how it threw an error when the package doesn't show an error what so ever, after rebuilds and cleans...

Comment: Can you also show the code for `LoginActivity` and `PLoginActivity` (what's the difference between these two anyhow?). Logcat suggests you may be extending from an Activity class that isn't available at runtime: `Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/limbones/profilelife/LoginActivity`.

Comment: FullCode posted, thank you guys.

Comment: I have just edited your question. Please read the FAQ on putting more appropriate titles. Also completely avoid ranting on how thankful or sorry you are, its a lot of text to read, and frankly noone on SO has that much time to read. Stick to the problem and be crisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the project setup. From your logcat:

```
11-29 11:38:41.642: W/dalvikvm(330): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/limbones/profilelife/LoginActivity; (462)
11-29 11:38:41.683: W/dalvikvm(330): Link of class 'Lcom/limbones/profilelife/LoginActivity;' failed
11-29 11:38:41.683: W/dalvikvm(330): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/limbones/profilelife/PLLoginActivity; (471)
11-29 11:38:41.683: W/dalvikvm(330): Link of class 'Lcom/limbones/profilelife/PLLoginActivity;' failed
```

Seems like you are missing the FacebookActivity?

Comment: That's weird, I remember clearly that I imported everything required for it. Could you clarify what you mean please?

Comment: well. logcat tells you that it cannot resolve the superclass of LoginActivity, which happens to be FacebookActivity. So I'd look for errors there first. And I do not mean imports, I think you do not have the FacebookActivity on your classpath during compile time.

Comment: Thank you... there wasn't a build path to the FacebookSDK. Apparently it was deleted at some point when I removed my other project. It didn't show an error until I restarted Eclipse. 1 hour of throttling in my seat wondering what the hell it was, and it was a damn build path. Thank you.

Comment: Quick question off topic. We should probably flag this as localized since I'm an idiot. But does it take away your rep points? I don't want you to lose them, you fully deserve it. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to put the facebook library files in your project libs folder, refresh and rebuild (clean).